# "The type or namespace name "Brick" could not be found" Xamarin Studio with MonoBrick

Tags: mindstorms, programming, ev3, monobrick

I managed to establish a wifi connection with the Ev3 Brick via WinSCD and am programming the Ev3 with XamarinStudio/Mono Develop(http://xamarin.com/studio "XamarinStudio"). My problem is that "The type or namespace name 'Brick' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
The Code is:

```
var ev3 = new Brick <TouchSensor, IRSensor, ColorSensor, ColorSensor>("wifi");
```

as you can see at the screenshot below...[image]

Comment: What are your Project `References` ?

Comment: The References are only the `MonoBrickFirmware.dll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using the standard [MonoBrick Communication Library](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/monobrick/) if you want to connect remotely to the EV3.

You would then need to have the following `using` statement at the top of your code:

```
using MonoBrick.Ev3
```

I believe you are referencing the [MonoBrick EV3 Firmware](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/ev3firmware/) which doesn't need to connect to the brick as it *is* the brick.